# Path=(dxg:GridViewBase.IsFocusedRow) for DevExpress what means?

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress controls and i'm overriding the row style for the grid control.
It works, but i don't know why for the binding of the row state we used:

```
{Binding Path=SelectionState}
```

and for the state of the focus this:

```
{Binding Path=(dxg:GridViewBase.IsFocusedRow)}
```

Why we use the namespace at start, then the GridViewBase (the row inherit from the GridViewBase?) and then the property?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsFocusedRow is attached property to GridView. 
More info about Attached properties: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hey thank you! I didn't knew about attached properties!